# Bitlocker no TPM found

Tags: windows, bitlocker, tpm

I would like to enable bitlocker on my C: drive, but I dont understand the following message:

[image]

If it's the hardware, which part exactly? I have a recent asus motherboard with UEFI. How can I find out if my motherboard supports TPM?

[image]

Comment: It’s a chip on the motherboard. What’s your board’s make and model?

Comment: @DanielB i have added a screenshot of cpuz about the mainboard.

Comment: The error indicates you don't have a TPM module.  Enable the option to allow Bitlocker to function without it

Comment: @Ramhound which option is that exactly?

Comment: @clamp - Read the error message it tells you exactly what to do.  If your hardware does not have  TPM module already, enabling that option, is really your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

[These](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/B85MG/specifications/) are your motherboard’s specs. It doesn’t mention a TPM at all. **That means your motherboard doesn’t have a TPM and you cannot install one.**

[These](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Q87ME/specifications/) are the specs of a motherboard featuring a built-in TPM. Note how the TPM is prominently advertised. Because this technology is largely irrelevant to consumers, there are only five Socket 1150 motherboards that have it.

There is yet another category of motherboards, with [this one](http://www.asus.com/de/Motherboards/B85ME/specifications/) being an example. They have a connector where you can install a TPM module. These modules are available starting from about $10.